# aspnet 2.0 GridView Get value CheckBox create dynamically

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, checkbox, gridview

I created an asp page with a GridView with a text column and n columns with dynamic checkboxes.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridAssetto" runat="server" Width="100%" GridLines="Vertical" SkinID="grdRegular" 
    EnableModelValidation="True" AllowPaging="false" 
    OnRowCommand="gridAssetto_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="gridAssetto_RowDataBound" 
    OnDataBound="gridAssetto_DataBound">                    
</asp:GridView>
```

In .cs

```
protected void gridAssetto_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < numCol; i++)
        {

            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
            cb.ID = "cb_Aero" + e.Row.Cells[0].Text + "_Ane" + 
            gridAssetto.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text;
            
            cb.EnableViewState = true;

            MutuallyExclusiveCheckBoxExtender cbExt = new MutuallyExclusiveCheckBoxExtender();
            cbExt.ID = "cbExt" + i;
            cbExt.TargetControlID = cb.ID;
            cbExt.EnableViewState = true;
            cbExt.Key = e.Row.RowIndex.ToString();
            e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(cb);
            e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(cbExt);
        }
```

I take the data from the database and set the checkboxes correctly with the method

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gridAssetto.Rows)
{
     CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)row.FindControl(cbID);

     if (chk != null)
       chk.Checked = true;
}
```

when instead I want to store the information on the database I have to read the checkboxes modified by the user, at click button the FindControl method does not work, as if the checkboxes in the grid were no longer there

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gridAssetto.Rows)
{
    for (int xx = 1; xx < row.Cells.Count; xx++)
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string idcell = row.Cells[xx].ID;

            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)row.Cells[xx].FindControl(cbID);

            if (chk != null)
            {
                if (chk.Checked)
                {
                    my code ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the chk is always null!
In the page html, before clic button, I have this control:

```
<input id="ctl00_Contenitore_TabGestione_TabAssetto_gridAssetto_ctl05_cb_AeroG001769_Ane1128" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$Contenitore$TabGestione$TabAssetto$gridAssetto$ctl05$cb_AeroG001769_Ane1128">
```

but when i read the check in debug code, i have the value

```
row.Cells[xx].ID is null and

row.Cells[xx].UniqueID is

"ctl00$Contenitore$TabGestione$TabAssetto$gridAssetto$ctl03$ctl00"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is PostBack.
Before postback I have the control checkbox, after click the button i lost control checkbox.

what is the solution to the problem?